# Angular ng-swagger-gen generate from many resourcees from one server

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, swagger

I using zuul with many swagger resources (I have different links to specifics api-docs) so my question is how can I configure ng-swagger-gen config to generate all classes from many resources?

This is my ng-swagger-gen config:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-swagger-gen/ng-swagger-gen-schema.json",
  "swagger": "http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs",
  "output": "src/api/",
  "apiModule": true
}
```

And this is my swagger confing in zuul application

```
@Primary
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {
    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        resources.add(swaggerResource("USER-SERVICE", "/api/user/v2/api-docs"));
        resources.add(swaggerResource("STORY-SERVICE", "/api/story/v2/api-docs"));
        return resources;
    }

private SwaggerResource swaggerResource(String name, String location) {
    SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
    swaggerResource.setName(name);
    swaggerResource.setLocation(location);
    swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
    return swaggerResource;
}
```

}